# Calculate Matrix A from eigenvalues, but no given eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is my question:

Write down a nontriangular 3 by 3 matrix whose eigenvalues are 6, 9, 2.

I understand that you can calulate Matrix A using the formula A=V$\Lambda$$V^-1$, but is there a way to calcuate the original matrix A from just eigenvalues.

Is there a way to construct Matrix A only using eigenvalues? Perhaps, using [v1, v2, v3,...] as placeholders?

Comment: Hint: The eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix are the entries in it's diagnoal...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is probably this: construct a $2\times2$ block with two of the eigenvalues, and then just use the other one. For instance
$$
\begin{bmatrix}15&9&0\\-6&0&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}
$$
The $2\times2$ block in the upper left corner has eigenvalues $6,9$.

For a more general way: You can grab any orthonormal basis $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ (as column vectors). If you now construct 
$$
A=2v_1v_1^T+6v_2v_2^T+9v_3v_3^T,
$$
then $A$ will have the desired eigenvalues.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Kaj_H's answer was helpful, but wasn't non-triangular. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many matrices A with such eigenvalues. Sure, you can use [v1, v2, v3] as placeholders for the eigenvectors, to build up the matrix V

Comment: Would those particular eigenvalues have infinte eigenvectors? Could I randomly pick a particular eigenvector Ex.[1,2,3] for eigenvalue=6 and do the same for the other eigenvalues and find one of the infinite matrices A for those partiuclar values and vectors?

Comment: @user2066723 yes

Answer (score 0):

One possible matrix would be:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 9 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 2  
\end{bmatrix}$$

Note that this matrix would not be unique.  If you are particularly clever, you can construct infinitely many matrices such that their characteristic equation had roots $9, 6$, and $2$.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me visualize how to proceed.

Comment: The matrix is supposed to be non-triangular.